# Rust reshape a vec into vec<vec>

Tags: vector, rust, casting

```rust
let a: Vec<f32>;
let mut new: Vec<Vec<f32>>;
```

Assume that `a` has a size of `n * n`. How can I convert it into a 2D vector `new`?
Obviously, it would be very naive to simply iterate over the vector and do it by hand. Is there any way to do a quick and performant reshape?

Comment: No, there would be too many different ways/use cases for this to be able to be included as part of the standard library. If you have a common use case, you might be able to find a crate to help, but this is probably something you'll need to write yourself. If you want to give an example of *how* it should be converted, you may be able to get an answer here.

Comment: You might go for a crate that implements similar functionality to numpy, like ndarray. Or, if `&[&[f32]]` is good enough for you, you could use `let new = a.chunks(n).collect::<Vec<_>>()`. That's `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

No. If you're coming from numpy or similar tooling, numpy stores all arrays as one-dimensional and does arithmetic to make it *look* multi-dimensional, so performantly reshaping an array really does just involve changing an index somewhere. But a `Vec` in Rust is a one-dimensional structure, and a `Vec<Vec<...>>` is a nested datatype with a completely different structure, so you will actually have to copy all of the elements to the new vector. Iterating over the elements is the right way, in this case.

I applaud your efforts to find a better way, but in this case I do believe the answer is to just do it yourself.

Comment: Or use a library for views like numpy's.